# Vagrant + Xdebug + Atom

Tags: vagrant, xdebug, atom-editor, php-ini

I have a vagrant box with xdebug installed, running on OSX, but Im struggling to get the Atom xdebug plugin (`php-debug`) to connect to it.

I pasted the `phpinfo();` data into the xdebug validation site and it said all was good. And you can see all the xdebug settings.

I have mapped port 9000 in the vagrant file.

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

The vagrant box has host only network that exposes `192.168.10.100` as the IP of the server.

And I've tried all manner of different xdebug options, the ones on the ATOM plugin site suggest..

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

But that is a slightly confusing as `remote_connect_back=1` means xdebug will ignore the `remote_host` setting - so not sure why both are in there - neither work.

I've restarted apache / php after each time I change the options, and check they are loaded with `phpinfo();`

If I check who is listening on port 9000

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Atom\x20H 10656 Matt   28u  IPv6 0x321cb0a96ba5b593      0t0  TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN)
VBoxHeadl 10889 Matt   19u  IPv4 0x321cb0a981a71433      0t0  TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

You can see both vagrant (virtual box) and Atom.  Although Atom is IPv6 which is odd....

But enabling the debugger in ATOM, setting a breakpoint and hitting the site, nothing happens - ATOM never connects.

Any ideas?  Anyone got this to work?

Comment: Where did you got those instructions from? Any specific manual? There seems to be misunderstanding in how xdebug works in general. 1) *"But that is a slightly confusing as remote_connect_back=1 means xdebug will ignore the remote_host setting"* You are correct -- that option is not needed there -- it better be set to `0`

Comment: 2) `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` -- this is wrong (unless you will be doing debugging via SSH tunnel). It must be an IP where debug client (Atom in your case) is running. It's xdebug that connects to client and NOT other way around: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote 3) This also means that the IP must be as seen from that Vagrant machine. Easiest way of getting it -- look at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: 4) This also means that you do not need to expose 9000 port in Vagrant -- nobody will be connecting to it (like you do with port 80 for web server) -- it's xdebug from VM/guest OS will be connecting outside to your "real"/host OS. If anything -- it should allow outgoing connections on that port instead of incoming. 5) *"If I check who is listening on port 9000"* this one means that Atom is unable to receive incoming xdebug connection over TCPv4 .. which xdebug will try to use by default

Comment: 6) If anything -- collect xdebug log (`xdebug.remote_log`) and see where it tries to connect etc.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne - I didn't realise that about xdebug connecting to the client, rather than the other way round. Makes sense.   The `REMOTE_ADDR` is `192.168.10.1`, so ill add that in and turn off `remote_connect_back` and see what happens....

Comment: I've now get the settings as simply...   `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` `xdebug.remote_enable=1` `xdebug.remote_host=192.168.10.1`, removed the vagrant port mapping but still nothing.  The `php-debug` plugin in Atom just says 'listening on port 9000..." and nothing happens.  must be an in issue with the plugin...

Comment: Please generate and then check xdebug log -- it may tell a different story.

Comment: @LazyOne, you star - got it working with your suggestions - I had an error in my last test, now its straight it works.  Cheers, if you post an answer ill mark is as correct.  Cheers mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But that is a slightly confusing as `remote_connect_back=1` means xdebug will ignore the `remote_host` setting

You are correct -- that option is not needed there -- it better be set to `0`

> xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1

This is wrong (unless you will be doing debugging via SSH tunnel). It must be an IP where debug client (Atom in your case) is running. **It's xdebug who connects to client** and NOT other way around: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

This also means that the IP must be as seen from that Vagrant machine. Possibly the easiest way of getting it -- look at what `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` has.

> I have mapped port 9000 in the vagrant file.
>
> `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000`

You do not need to expose 9000 port in Vagrant -- nobody will be connecting to it (like you do with port 80 for web server) -- it's xdebug from VM/guest OS will be connecting outside to your "real"/host OS.

If anything -- you should be allowing outgoing connections on that port instead of incoming.

> If I check who is listening on port 9000

This one means that Atom is unable to receive incoming xdebug connection over TCPv4 .. which xdebug will try to use by default (unless you specify IPv6 address in `xdebug.remote_host`).

---

If anything -- collect xdebug log (`xdebug.remote_log`) and see where it tries to connect etc.

Answer (score 0):

@LazyOne already answered this question, but issue I had was caused by antivirus (MCAfee) which was blocking incoming traffic. Maybe this will help someone in the future.