# Homestead Vagrant Failt to boot the VM: "The VMMR0.r0 module version does not match VBoxVMM.dll/so/dylib"

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, vagrantfile

I tried to follow the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302256/4706711) and make the xdebug installed to vagrant to get connected into the atom.

So in my `Vagrantfile` I have put the following setting:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

Resulting the following `Vagrantfile` is:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("vendor/laravel/homestead", File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("Homestead.yaml", File.dirname(__FILE__))
homesteadJsonPath = File.expand_path("Homestead.json", File.dirname(__FILE__))
afterScriptPath = "after.sh"
aliasesPath = "aliases"

require File.expand_path(confDir + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.9.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if defined? VagrantPlugins::HostsUpdater
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
end
```

And I tried to start it via the following command:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

But I get the following error:

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["startvm", "12135e8c-7547-4c7e-a25c-58a7136fb600", "--type", "headless"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The VMMR0.r0 module version does not match VBoxVMM.dll/so/dylib. If you just upgraded VirtualBox, please terminate all VMs and make sure that neither VBoxNetDHCP nor VBoxNetNAT is running. Then try again. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox. (VERR_VMM_R0_VERSION_MISMATCH)
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

My version of Virtualbox is the `5.1.38_Ubuntur122592` one (from command `VboxManage -v`).

Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vagrant-up/ZtWf5zTQaJY/LOK50sb2AQAJ

Comment: I have tried this one ending up without being able to create host-only adapters.

Comment: I dont see any network setting in your Vagrantfile

Comment: Another one-ines solution that works for many [ref](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/483#issuecomment-221948437): `sudo killall VBoxHeadles`.

Comment: @vulcanraven This worked for me after applying Dimitrios 's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow these steps mentioned in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vagrant-up/ZtWf5zTQaJY/LOK50sb2AQAJ). The steps are:

First uninstall the virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox virtualbox-ose virtualbox-qt
```

Then run the following command:

```
find / -name '*VMMR0*' -o -name '*VBoxVMM*'
```

Then install it back:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-qt
```

Afterwards `cd` to your project's root path and run

```
vagrant up
```

In my case I had to repeat these steps twice in order to make it working.