# Atom IDE and Xdebug Vagrant with Homestead and php-debug: Cannot make it pause execution to a breakpoint and debug

Tags: php, vagrant, atom-editor, xdebug, symfony-3.4

I try to make my Xdebug running inside a Homestead Vagrant VM to connect into the Atom IDE. So via `vagrant ssh` I created an SSH connection and typed the following commands:

```
xon
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

Based on that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254964/vagrant-xdebug-atom) I have put the following settings to `20-xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
xdebug.remote_host= 10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

Then my Atom configuration is the following:

```
"*":
  "atom-autocomplete-php":
    autoloadPaths: [
      "vendor/autoload.php"
    ]
    binComposer: "/usr/bin/composer "
    binPhp: "/usr/bin/php"
    classMapFiles: [
      "vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php"
    ]
    insertNewlinesForUseStatements: true
  "atom-package-deps":
    ignored: []
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    fontSize: 13
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "9f9c6aa7-2152-104d-a113-56d710236d00"
  linter: {}
  "linter-ui-default":
    panelHeight: 300
  "php-debug":
    DebugXDebugMessages: true
    currentPanelHeight: "357px"
    currentPanelMode: "bottom"
    currentPanelWidth: "493px"
    server:
      keepAlive: true
      protocolDebugging: true
      redirectStderr: true
      redirectStdout: true
      serverPort: 9001
    showWelcome: false
    xdebug:
      pathMaps: "[{\"remotePath\":\"/home/vagrant/code/\",\"localPath\":\"/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/ellakcy_member_app/\"}]"
  "tree-view":
    autoReveal: true
    hideVcsIgnoredFiles: true
```

And I configured my Firefox's "Xdebug Helper" plugin like that:

[image: Firefox Xdebug Helper]

But when I place some breakpoint to my code the execution does not stop to them/ not shown. Also over my Homestead I ping into the IP that is getting connected back like that:

```
vagrant@ellakcy-member-app:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d$ ping 10.0.2.2
PING 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.121 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
^C^C
--- 10.0.2.2 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, t
```

Further investigation proves that the Homestead VM is able to get connected to my host via netcat (the command is running inside the VM):

```
nc -z -v -w5 10.0.2.2 9001
Connection to 10.0.2.2 9001 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

So what else I am missing/misconfigured and how I can figure out how to fix it?

## Edit 1

Further investigation proved that the `php-debug` starts and ends the debug session without stopping to any breakpoint as PHP Console tells:

[image: Log to the atom ide]

Do you know why suddenly the debug session even if it has some breakpoints is getting terminated?

## Edit 2

I changed my xdebug settings into:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9091
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

Then I change the listening port into `9091`. The ide key is changed into `atom-xdebug` but still I cannot make it stop to a breakpoint. Also when runnin gover cli cannot write into `/var/log/xdebug.log`. Should I generate it manually?

Also I tried to enforce a breakpoint with `xdebug_break()` still no result.

Also my path mappings are:

```
[{"remotePath":"/home/vagrant/code/","localPath":"/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/ellakcy_member_app/"}]
```

And my local path is consisted of these files:

[image]

The project is written on symfony 3.4 as well.

Comment: 1) Check what Xdebug log has to say -- maybe it connects to wrong IP; see the actual communication etc. 2) It will also tell (once connection is successfully established) what file it tries to debug. Maybe you have somehow wrong path mappings .. or unexpected file gets executed. 3) Have you tried putting `xdebug_break();` into the actual code? **P.S.** with `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` the `xdebug.remote_host` value will be ignored (unless it cannot detect the caller IP).

Comment: I edited the question providing more info. I both used the `xdebug_break()` still fail to connect via xdebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the atom to work with vagrant you should use the following xdebug settings:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_port = 9091
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log
```

Keep in mind with typos eg. `xdebuf` also in order for the atom editor to manage correctly the path use the following mapping:

```
[{"remotePath":"/home/vagrant/code/","localPath":"^local_project_root^"}]
```

Where `^local_project_root^` is the top-level folder containing the whole source code (in your case where `ellakcy_member_app` is located).

Also **uncheck** these options as well as the image shows:

[image]

In makes the atom not to work properly on breakpoints if checked. In case you have heaps of projects then remove them from your tree view and ensure you keep only one. You can add them later and continue working.